# How can I find the cost of an already removed resource on Azure?

Tags: azure

We redeployed some of our Azure resources under new resource and resource group names. Now, when I go to cost analysis and filter by resource group I can't find the previous instance of those resources.

Is there a way to do reports on the cost of removed resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you're looking for from Cost Management Section as shown in the below image.

[image: Cost analysis in Cost Management section - Azure Portal]

Comment: The image is missing.